# How can I mirror/copy/sync some CSS properties from one HTML element to another using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an HTML element that gets it's `width/height/transform/translate` CSS properties modified using the `style` attributed by a third-party library that handles image zoom and panning.

I hooked into this library's lifecycle events to add a mouse-hover overlay on top of the image, and I would like to sync the `width/height/transform/translate` properties of the base image to the overlayed image.

Is there a way to detect these changes and copy the styles without polling at regular intervals?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of copy paste the information try to create a responsive way of displaying the overlayed image using % or even em/rem. If you need further help can you showcase an example?